# dreamweaver live view alternative

Tags: html, firebug, dreamweaver, live-preview

Are there any IDE's that have live html rendering which updates on save? I don't like Dreamweaver's live view because it reloads the entire page/css/js making it slow... I want something more similar to firebug which just changes the specific element. I was thinking something like a notepad++ plugin with the firebug api. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [skybound stylizer 5](http://www.skybound.ca/) to be perfect for this application. It's a css editor and it watches the file and when modified, it automatically reloads the page. It also has support for many browsers.